# How about start a new long time thread in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net

We have a rank list method, which takes 5 miniustes to complete.

We cache the list in memcache , but when the cache expires, It will blocks all the request.

So I want to cache both the list and cache time in memcache together, and set a long expire time.

Every time gets the list from memcache, the programme also checks the cache time, if it over 1 hours, the programme starts a new thread which regenerates the rank list, programme returns the old list immediately,

So, there is no block in the programme.

The problem is , is it correct starting a new tread in asp.net ? if the new thread be killed when the aspx thread response end?

And how to resolve the spread cache lock ??? we use 3 iis servers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `App_Start` in Global.asax to get a thread that isn't tied to a request but you should be aware it still has limitations (eg the worker pool might kill it after a length of time).

Have a look here for more information : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25722&seqNum=8

Answer (score 0):

You must firstly increase  your timeout of application, you can set in your config file.
In order to not disconnect

```
<system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.80).aspx

For caching you can use different persistent caching systems : Session, Cache or Application

if you use `Cache` you can set TimeSpan for time of persisting

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use http-handler. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
It works as a thread and you can access any thing `session`, `cache` etc there.
For this you will have to use `IRequiresSessionState`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

And you can call it from any where. 
From `code behind` or from `jquery`